# How do I filter out all the *Magic: the Gathering* questions?

Tags: support

Suppose I am not interested in *Magic: the Gathering*. How do I filter out all the *Magic: the Gathering* questions?

Answer (score 7):

If you go to your [Preferences](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/) page at the bottom of the page there is a place to put in favorite and ignored tags. Put magic-the-gathering (and any other Magic tags like mtg-commander) in there, and if you want to hide them completly choose the 'Hide questions in your ignored tags' option.

Comment: I do this with [bridge] because it's incomprehensible to me. It works well. \o/ (no offense meant to bridge players.)

Comment: Ignoring [magic-the-gathering] should be sufficient to hid every question about Magic. If there is a question tagged [mtg-commander] but not [magic-the-gathering], that is an error that should be corrected.

Comment: You could also add `mtg-*` to the ignored tags, which should ignore all tags beginning with `mtg-`. (Caveat: In case a game’s name starts with "mtg-", and it’s not related to *MtG*, it would be blocked, too, of course.)

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to going to your preferences page, is to hover over any question's tags on any page until the hover tooltip opens up. Then, click the Star twice to turn it into a red cross. This effectively puts it in your ignored tags.

[image: Ignore a tag]