# Hide specific Questions

Tags: support

Is there a way to hide specific questions?

Merely to hide questions that while still in your interest categories, are but perhaps already answered, or the exact topic doesn't interest you.

*This is not the same as hiding entire topics or tags (Discussed here: [How do I filter out all the *Magic: the Gathering* questions?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/how-do-i-filter-out-all-the-magic-the-gathering-questions/1485#1485))*

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you cannot do this. The only question hiding functionality is by hiding tags as you mentioned.