# How can I hide ignored-tagged questions?

Tags: support, tags

Supposedly there's a "Hide questions in your ignored tags" option, but I don't see it. Screenshot?

[How do I filter out all the *Magic: the Gathering* questions?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/how-do-i-filter-out-all-the-magic-the-gathering-questions/1485#1485)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be right in the ignored tag section.

[image]

Comment: I don't have anything that looks like that.

Comment: You have to click the "edit" button.

Comment: What edit button?

Comment: @Jessy That appears when you go to edit your ignored tag list on the main page of the site.

Comment: I see. The information at the link is incorrect. There's no way to do it from "Edit profile and settings". I didn't know that box was even over there on the right.

Comment: @Jessy They have been changing the interface over the years and it could have been correct at the time it was written but have changed since then.